# ToastActionsCreators is not defined when using react-native-redux-toast

Tags: react-native, redux

I am unable to call ToastActionsCreators when using react-native-redux-toast

I get a ToastActionsCreators is not defined error when I call this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayInfo("Info toast!", 2000)); in my screen component. Anyone knows how to resolve this?

In my react native debugger, I am able to see the toast reducer passed in by react-native-redux-toast. However, I have a problem calling the actions

Thank you

Here is sample of my code

**In Redux Screen**

```
class ReduxScreen extends Component {
  _displayInfoToast = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayInfo("Info toast!", 2000));
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { counter } = this.props.test;
    const { textStyle } = styles;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={textStyle}>{counter.toString()} </Text>
        <Button title="INCREMENT" onPress={this.props.incrementCounter} />
        <Button title="DECREMENT" onPress={this.props.decrementCounter} />
        <Button title="SHOW TOAST" onPress={this._displayInfoToast} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // console.log(state);
  return {
    test: state.test
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      incrementCounter,
      decrementCounter
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ReduxScreen);
```

**In reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import testReducer from "./testReducer";
import { toastReducer as toast } from "react-native-redux-toast";

export default combineReducers({
  // test: () => []
  test: testReducer,
  toast
});
```

I did not add any code to my actions file pertaining to react-native-redux-toast since its node needed

I am using react navigation createDrawerNavigator for navigation

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.ignoredYellowBox = ["Setting a timer"];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MyProvider>
            <Drawer />
            <Toast messageStyle={{ color: "white" }} />
          </MyProvider>
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Full Code
https://github.com/myhendry/demo/tree/master/src/redux

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing ToastActionCreators in `ReduxScreen.js`. That's why it's undefined; you haven't defined it anywhere in that file.

Comment: Hi. I added import { ToastActionsCreators } from "react-native-redux-toast"; however, it still can't work. I suspect the reason is that the actionCreators make available by the module is not passed down to my ReduxScreen. Im still trying to figure out a solution for it

Comment: After I added in the ToastActionCreators, i get the following error _this.props.dispatch is not a function. I was able to get my own custom action creators working but not the ToastActionCreators

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work! By doing below, it added in the dispatch function available in my props which allow me to call this.props.dispatch to dispatch the ToastActionCreators action creator to the store to show the toast.

Hope this will help others. Cheers

in my ReduxScreen.js, i added in the following...

```
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ToastActionsCreators } from "react-native-redux-toast";

import { incrementCounter, decrementCounter } from "./actions/index";

  _displayInfoToast = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayInfo("Info toast!", 2000));
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    ...bindActionCreators({ incrementCounter, decrementCounter }, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ReduxScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ***[react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify)*** package.

**npm i --save react-toastify**

```
// Simply import these two objects:  
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';     

  // Then make a toast function, something like this:
        success = () => toast.info("Data successfully saved", { autoClose: 2000 });

  // Somewhere in your code use your success toast function, like this:

saveNewUser = (data) => {
        getUsers.addUser(data).then(res=> {
            this.success();                     // Here we trigger the that toast        
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error while adding new user', error);
            throw(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
            const {userData} = this.state;
    return (
            <div className="container">

            // ...your logic goes here. This is just my example:
                       <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {userData}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

        // Here we trigger our function that will also trigger our success toast :)
                        <button type="button"
                         onClick={this.saveNewUser}>   
                         Save new user </button>

       // Then just before the last closing </div> insert this
      <ToastContainer autoClose={3000} closeOnClick />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was looking at react native redux toast because it is linked to redux. I like controlling displaying of toast in my actions rather than in my components which I try to keep to presentational